# Extracting only first appearance from a list of patterns in R

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I have a list of country names and a dataframe containing one column of text and one column of binary indicators.

MWE:

```
rm(list=ls())

library(countrycode)
country_list <- countrycode::codelist$country.name.en

Text <- c("This is","a test to", "find country", "names like Algeria", "Albania and Afghanistan","in the data","and return only the","first match in each","string, Algeria and Albania", "not Afghanistan")
df <- as.data.frame(Text)
df$ofInterest <- c(0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0)
```

I want to return the first word (and only the first word) in `df$Text` that matches any element in `country_list`. In other words, I'm only interested in the very first country name that gets mentioned.

The operation should create a new column in `df` indicating the matched country name, or **NA** if no matches from `country_list` were found, for each row.

To make things faster, I also want to restrict the search to rows where `df$ofInterest==1`.

In other words, it should return the following:

```
Text                       ofInterest   Match
This is                     0           NA   
a test to                   0           NA
find country                0           NA
names like Algeria          1           Algeria
Albania and Afghanistan     1           Albania
in the data                 1           NA
and return only the         0           NA
first match in each         0           NA
string, Algeria and Albania 1           Algeria
not Afghanistan             0           NA
```

My problem is that I don't know how to use regex while also pattern matching from a list. How can I do this in R?

This was as far as I can get. The "*xxxxx*" is presumably where the `country_name` list should go.

This is probably a simple problem, but I couldn't find the solution. Thank you for any help!

```
df$Match <- ifelse(str_extract(df$Text, "(?<=^| )xxxxx.*?(?=$| )") %in% country_list, str_extract(df$Text, "(?<=^| )xxxxx.*?(?=$| )"), NA)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```r
df$Match <- str_extract(df$Text, paste0("(?i)\\b(", paste(country_list, collapse="|"), ")\\b"))
df <- within(df, Match[ofInterest == '0'] <- NA)
# > df
#                           Text ofInterest   Match
# 1                      This is          0    <NA>
# 2                    a test to          0    <NA>
# 3                 find country          0    <NA>
# 4           names like Algeria          1 Algeria
# 5      Albania and Afghanistan          1 Albania
# 6                  in the data          1    <NA>
# 7          and return only the          0    <NA>
# 8          first match in each          0    <NA>
# 9  string, Algeria and Albania          1 Algeria
# 10             not Afghanistan          0    <NA>
```

Here, `paste0("(?i)\\b(", paste(country_list, collapse="|"), ")\\b")` will create a pattern like

- `(?i)` - case insensitive matching
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(` - start of a capturing group:

  - `paste(country_list, collapse="|")` will result in a `|`-separated list of country names, like `Albania|Poland|France` etc.
- `)` - end ofthe group
- `\b` - word boundary.

The `df <- within(df, Match[ofInterest == '0'] <- NA)` will revert `NA` in all `Match` rows where `ofInterest` columnn value is `0`.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution, which is based on `intersect` with `country_list`, after having split each phrase into separate words, and taking the first element of the intersection:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(countrycode)

df %>% 
  rowwise %>% 
  mutate(Match = if_else(ofInterest == 1,
   intersect(unlist(str_split(Text,"\\s")), country_list)[1], NA_character_)) %>%
  ungroup

#> # A tibble: 10 × 3
#>    Text                        ofInterest Match  
#>    <chr>                            <dbl> <chr>  
#>  1 This is                              0 <NA>   
#>  2 a test to                            0 <NA>   
#>  3 find country                         0 <NA>   
#>  4 names like Algeria                   1 Algeria
#>  5 Albania and Afghanistan              1 Albania
#>  6 in the data                          1 <NA>   
#>  7 and return only the                  0 <NA>   
#>  8 first match in each                  0 <NA>   
#>  9 string, Algeria and Albania          1 Algeria
#> 10 not Afghanistan                      0 <NA>
```